# What does じゅう mean In the word string :いちにちじゅう

Tags: words

I am not familiar with じゅう and I wasn't able to find references to how it is used. Can someone explain to me what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search it just as is in the dictionary and you will get this.
一日中 : all day long; all the day; throughout the day.

I am leaving up to you the pleasure of discovering the countless ways of using the kanji 中, but let's just say for now that when it is read as じゅう it usually means "through; throughout; in the course of"